# How do i set up path and folder pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, path

So I am trying to set up path for my pdf files that are stored in a folder structure. The file that has to be selected depends on the user input. 
I want to set up first the absolute path and then a folder pattern.

The folder where I have stored my files is:

> C:\Apache24\htdocs\archivedb\Tourenfahrer\2017\5

The last three folders changes as per user input.

I have setup my root directory in my config.php like this:

```
define( 'ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) );
```

Now in my php file I am recieving my variables, which will be my folder names to search for the files.

```
<?php
require_once 'conf/config.php';


if (!empty($_REQUEST['magName'] && $_REQUEST['year'] && $_REQUEST['issue'] 
)) {

$magazineName = $_REQUEST['magName'];
$year = $_REQUEST['year'] ;
$issue = $_REQUEST['issue'] ;



}
```

Now Please tell how to access the respective folder using these variables?
and how can i set up a pattern with this using **glob();** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (!empty($_REQUEST['magName'] && $_REQUEST['year'] && $_REQUEST['issue'])) {
    $magazineName = $_REQUEST['magName'];
    $year = $_REQUEST['year'];
    $issue = $_REQUEST['issue'];
    $dir = $magazineName . DS . $year . DS . $issue;

    echo "<h3>Use scandir:</h3>";
    $files = scandir(ROOT_DIR . DS . $dir);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo basename($file) . "<br>";
    }

    echo "<h3>Use glob:</h3>";
    foreach (glob($dir . DS . '*') as $filename) {
        echo basename($filename) . "<br>";
    }
}
```